# Quarkus caching and metrics working but not really

Tags: quarkus

What I want?
To use caching and metrics

Why?

- Faster response
- Some metric data to evaluate things like: total hits, average duration, minimum duration, max duration... etc

I tried:

```
@CacheResult
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

```
@SimplyTimed
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-metrics</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Applied both of them like:

```
@GET
@CacheResult(cacheName = "someData")
@SimplyTimed
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> getSome() {
  return ... some data;
}
```

Both work as expected (on the first call)... sweet!

The thing is, because caching only runs the method on the first call, subsequent calls are handled straight through the cache and the metrics are no longer recorded.

I know that quarkus-cache extension is still on preview. As far as I know, microprofile have no business with caching.

And yes...

"Micrometer is the recommended approach to metrics for Quarkus. Use the SmallRye Metrics extension when it’s required to retain MicroProfile specification compatibility."

At this point I didn't find any objective/elegant solution through micrometer. From what I saw so far, I would have to abandon quarkus-cache and quarkus-smallrye-metrics and work manually with Caffeine and micrometer metrics.

Which brings me to the question: is there any possibility for quarkus-cache to keep metrics recording work out of the box, whether is annotation quarkus-smallrye-metrics or any other annotation metrics framework alike?

As explained before, the constraints about quarkus-cache and quarkus-smallrye-metrics "looks like" mutually exclusive. I understand that's a tough call. Please, go easy on me, ok?

Comment: "At this point I didn't find any objective/elegant solution through micrometer. From what I saw so far, I would have to abandon quarkus-cache and quarkus-smallrye-metrics and work manually with Caffeine and micrometer metrics."

That is an odd impression. If you turn on micrometer metrics (and leave the cached annotation), you should have http.server.requests.* metrics for that endpoint automatically, and those metrics are collected when the response is written (so should be captured whether or not the cache is used).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that @SimplyTimed is not executed a second time, and your metrics will not update until the cache expires or is invalidated. When you use @CacheResult, the method is intercepted and not actually executed; you cannot debug inside it either. Additionally, I had a bad experience when setting @CacheResult directly on the resource with a Request param.

A possible solution is to apply the @SimplyTimed annotation to the resource and @CachResult to an internal method.

```
import io.quarkus.cache.CacheResult;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics.annotation.SimplyTimed;

@ApplicationScoped
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

  @GET
  @SimplyTimed
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<String> getSome() {
    return getList();
  }

  @CacheResult(cacheName = "someData")
  public static List<String> getList() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return List.of("one", "two", "three");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since with these libraries code generation happens at build time, sometimes it matters in which sequence you use the annotations or even in rare cases, like with lombok, the sequence of dependencies.

So as a wild guess it might be worth to try adding the metrics first:

```java
@GET
@SimplyTimed //<-------------------------------/ like this
@CacheResult(cacheName = "someData") //<------/
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> getSome() {
  return ... some data;
}
```